# issue httpresponseredirect:unable to redirect to homepage

Tags: python, html, django

I’m keeping getting this redirect wrong either I got the code wrong or it keeps running in an infinite loop.

urls.py first app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.pomo,name="pomo"),
    path("agenda/",views.agenda,name="agenda"),
    path("notes/",views.notes,name="notes"),
  ]
```

urls.py main

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('pomofocus.urls')), 
    path ("login/", include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

urls.py accounts(2nd app)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("register/",views.register_request, name="register")
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #save user
            user = form.save()
            #login user
            login(request,user)
            #send success message 
            messages.success(request,"Congrats you are registered now")
            return redirect(“pomofocus:pomo")
        
        messages.error(request,"Unsuccesful registration.Try again.")
    form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request,"account/registration.html",context={"register_form":form})
```

Comment: `return redirect('pomo')`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just tried but once the form is sent it returns the same page

Comment: ah, but that is because you rerender the template when the form is invalid.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and how can i solve this problem?

Comment: render the invalid form. Django forms will, if you render these with `{{ register_form }}` display the errors per field and non-field related items at the top

Answer (score 1):

You create a new form if the POST request is unsuccessful. You should keep the old form, such that errors can be displayed. You thus should change the logic such that you only create a *new* form in case the request is not a POST request:

```
from django.contrib import messages

def register_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #save user
            user = form.save()
            #login user
            login(request,user)
            #send success message 
            messages.success(request, 'Congrats you are registered now')
            return redirect('pomo')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Unsuccesful registration.Try again.')
    else:  # ← only in case it is not a POST request
        form = NewUserForm()
    return render(request,'account/registration.html', {'register_form': form})
```